# How do I read the whole 64 bytes of a binary file?

Tags: c++, binary, partitioning, disk, istream

I am writing a little program that reads a disk image file in binary and then checks its partition entry tables to display each partition, it's type, start sector and size.

So far it reads the first 16 bytes accurately but the rest of the partition entries are not recognized or have some kind of error.
The result looks like this:
[image]
EDIT: The first line of the output is supposed to look like this:

```
 `Partition 0: Type: FAT-16 Start: 63 Size: 518760`
```

What am I missing? How do I fix the code so that all the partition entries give the appropriate result?

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

struct Partition { char type; int start_sect; int size; } part_entry[4];  // 4 x partition table entry 


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
//DECLARATIONS
int i, offset = 26, not_exist = 0;
char buf_part_table[64], vol_type[12];
char* diskdata;
int n;
streampos begin, end;


ifstream diskimage;
diskimage.open("Sample_1.dd", ios::in | ios::binary | ios::out);


diskdata = new char[begin];
begin = diskimage.tellg();
diskdata = new char[begin];
diskimage.seekg(446, ios::beg);

diskimage.read(buf_part_table, 64);


for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    part_entry[i].type = *(char*)(buf_part_table + 0x04 + (i * offset));

    if (part_entry[i].type == 0) not_exist++;

    part_entry[i].start_sect = *(int*)(buf_part_table + 0x08 + (i * offset));

    part_entry[i].size = *(int*)(buf_part_table + 0x0C + (i * offset));

    switch (part_entry[i].type)
    {
    case 00:  strcpy(vol_type, "NOT-VALID");
        break;
    case 06:  strcpy(vol_type, "FAT-16");
        break;
    case 07:  strcpy(vol_type, "NTFS");
        break;
    case 0x0B:  strcpy(vol_type, "FAT-32");
        break;
    default:    strcpy(vol_type, "NOT-DECODED");
        break;
    }

    cout << "Partition " << i << ":" << " Type:" << vol_type << " Start: " << part_entry[i].start_sect << " Size: " << part_entry[i].size << endl;

}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don't post images of text (especially as links), instead copy-paste the actual text, as text, into the body of the question. And if you have unexpected output, it also helps to see the *expected* output, not only the actual.

Comment: `buf_part_table + 0xXX + (i * offset)` with `i == 3` goes far from 64 bytes. May be `offset` should be a 16, not 26?

Comment: [texts are not supposed to be posted in images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714)

Comment: How it even compile for you as it is missing `#include <cstring>` ?

Comment: @Anty Sometimes some header files include other header files.

Comment: struct Partition will contain padding, does this match the layout of the data?  The (int*) casts are undefined behaviour (and may not meet alignment requirements) use memcpy instead.

Comment: what was the input, and what did you expect to get as output ?

Comment: How do you know `int` is 64-bits?  (hint: you don't -- use `int64_t` instead)  Also, you appear to be using offsets that increase by 4 bytes, which would imply 32-bits.  And +1 to @RichardCritten for pointing out aliasing issues with type-punning on a character buffer.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I will update the photo, I actually missed that, in the photo the first line was supposed to display:
Partition 0: Type: FAT-16 Start: 63 Size: 518760

Comment: @RichardCritten How would I use memcpy in this case?

Comment: as I said, do not post the photo. If it's text, copy as is. Isn't there copy functionality in cmd.exe?

Comment: @em2er i had glossed over your comment originally but your are totally right, the offset should be a 16 not a 26, that is what was causing the wrong results. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You unnecesary made program unreadable and harder to debug.
You can read whole boot sector at once and than display desired content.
Here is my quick example (it does not check if file exists, some may complain it should use memcpy for some fields etc.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

struct partition_t {
    uint8_t  status;
    uint8_t  start_CHS[3];
    uint8_t  type;
    uint8_t  end_CHS[3];
    uint32_t start_LBA;
    uint32_t size_LBA;
} __attribute__((packed));

struct mbr_t
{
    uint8_t     bootstrap[446];
    partition_t partitions[4];
    uint16_t    signature;
} __attribute__((packed));

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    mbr_t mbr;
    ifstream diskimage;
    diskimage.open( "/tmp/mbr.dd", ios::in | ios::binary );
    diskimage.read( reinterpret_cast<char*>(&mbr), sizeof(mbr) );
    diskimage.close();

    for( int idx = 0 ; idx < 4 ; idx++ )
    {
      string bootable = (mbr.partitions[idx].status == 128) ? "yes" : "no";
      cout << " bootable : " <<  setw(5) << bootable << 
              " type : " << setw(5) << (int)mbr.partitions[idx].type << 
              " start LBA : " << setw(10) << mbr.partitions[idx].start_LBA << 
              " size : " << setw(10) << mbr.partitions[idx].size_LBA << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It is easier to read, right?

Comment: It's not much easier to read in truth, I see that it would display the information I need but not in the format I need it, I should relate the type from int to string where the int corresponds to a one of predefined set of types, ie `FAT-16, FAT-32, NTFS,`

Comment: It is example - adding new features like partition type to string is straightforward. Main goal was to reduce obscure read and pointer arithmetic.

Comment: `__attribute__((packed));`
What is "packed", its showing up as undefined.

`setw(5) <<` This says that no operator "<<" matches these operands.

Please how do I resolve that?

Comment: `bootable :    no type :    63 start LBA : 3621847040 size :          7`

 `bootable :    no type :    63 start LBA : 2956984328 size :         15`

` bootable :    no type :    63 start LBA : 2740387864 size :          5`

`bootable :    no type :     0 start LBA :          0 size : 2857697280 `

This is the output of your code.

Comment: You need to compile it with GCC or clang. __attribute__((packed)) prevents compiler from padding data to maintain default alignment. setw(5) is stream formating (set width 5). What compiler you use?